# Flutter - No Such Method Error: The method '[]' was called on null. receiver: null tried calling [] (0)

Tags: flutter, flutter-android, flutter-image, flutter-video-player, flutter-design

I'm trying to open the camera in my app after pressing a button to capture images and videos. But I'm getting this message when I test it -
NoSuchMethodError: The method '[]' was called on null. receiver: null tried calling [] (0)
[image: image containing error message]

I'm new to flutter and I believe my code has gotten a little messy.
Here is the link to my code

[cameraTestcodegithub](https://github.com/MaahdiCodes/camerainapptesting.git)

Can anyone help me with this, please?

Comment: you are calling 0th index of an empty array

Comment: @BenjithKizhisseri I don't have enough knowledge to solve it. Do you know how to solve this issue?